# How to reboot Erlang System automatically when there is a crash

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, erlang-ports

I am seeing the below error in my Erlang System:

```
(SystemLimitError) a system limit has been reached
```

How can I reboot the system on its own when it hits the **system limit error**?

I tried using the below start up command but that seems to be not rebooting the system, please help

```
iex --erl "-heart -env HEART_BEAT_TIMEOUT 30 +K true" -S mix
```

Comment: You did not set HEART_COMMAND, see http://erlang.org/doc/man/heart.html

Answer (score 0):

looks like you can't start anymore processes. it doesn't look like erlang crashed, but no new processes can be spawned until some old ones finish. If your test function hangs and doesn't finish, sooner or later you will run out of memory, but it looks like you've reached a limit on number of processes you can start first. If you want to increase the limit see http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#max_processes